# Windows Phone 8: Read XML/RSS with HTML spec chars

Tags: html, xml, vb.net, windows-phone-8, rss

I have an RSS feed (I have no control over it) but it has some HTML special characters in (specifically `&pound;`) is there any way in VB I can remove these? I tried using the below but it didn't work.

```
Dim Fixer As String = e.Result
Fixer.Replace("&pound;", "")
Dim resultElements As XElement = XElement.Parse(Fixer)
```

Help is appriciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try [HttpUtility.HtmlDecode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httputility.htmldecode%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)?

You should use this conversion probably on every textfield instead of the full XML. If there are > or similar, you will destroy the XML.